# "Until they see the kingdom of God" in Luke 9:27 and parallels

Tags: matthew, luke, mark, synoptics

What are the possible interpretations of "will not taste death until they see the kingdom of God"? Which is most likely correct?

[Luke 9:27](http://www.literalword.com/?q=luke+9%3A27):

> But I say to you truthfully, there are some of those standing here who will not taste death until they see the kingdom of God.”

[Mark 9:1](http://www.literalword.com/?q=mark+9%3A1):

> And Jesus was saying to them, “Truly I say to you, there are some of those who are standing here who will not taste death until they see the kingdom of God after it has come with power.”

[Matt. 16:28](http://www.literalword.com/?q=matt+16%3A28):

> “Truly I say to you, there are some of those who are standing here who will not taste death until they see the Son of Man coming in His kingdom.”

Comment: Are you looking for interpretations as to what event is anticipated by "the kingdom of God" coming in power?

Comment: @Soldarnal: Exactly.

Comment: The Kingdom of God is often used to refer to the Church as established by Peter on the day of Pentecost after the death of Christ. It is more inclusive of the group that is standing there when this teaching is taking place and also fits in with the fact that some will die before the ushering in of the Kingdom with the Holy Spirit being sent upon those in the upper room and then Peter preaches his sermon in Acts 2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Popular interpretations as to what event is anticipated by "the kingdom of God" coming in power include the following:

- The transfiguration
- The resurrection
- The ascension
- The day of Pentecost
- The second coming

A couple things stand out in the passage that are worth noting. First, Jesus has just given indication that the disciples may end up soon forfeiting their lives for his sake. Moreover he links this to his own impending death. Second, Jesus says that "some" will see this event, likely indicating that not all present will experience it. And third, the transfiguration story immediately follows this statement in each of the synoptic accounts. The connection is especially clear in Luke's account where he notes that "eight days after Jesus said this" they went up to the mountain.

Together these indicate that the transfiguration is likely the event anticipated. Unlike the second coming, it was fairly imminent. (And of course if it was the second coming, Jesus seems to be wrong.) The reference to "some" indicates that likely the resurrection, ascension or Pentecost are not in view since essentially all present to hear these words were present at those events as well. Judas is of course an exception, but "some" probably indicates a smaller group still. In contrast, only Peter, John and James were present at the transfiguration. The proximity of the pericopes is probably the most telling.

Outside of the synoptics, probably the most deciding passage comes from 2 Peter 1:16-18:

> [2 Peter 1:16-18 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:5-7&version=NIV) <sub>Emphasis added</sub>
>   <sup>16</sup>For we did not follow cleverly devised stories when we told you about the **coming of our Lord Jesus Christ in power**, but we were eyewitnesses of his majesty. <sup>17</sup>He received honor and glory from God the Father when the voice came to him from the Majestic Glory, saying, “This is my Son, whom I love; with him I am well pleased.” <sup>18</sup>We ourselves heard this voice that came from heaven **when we were with him on the sacred mountain**.

It is evident in these verses that Peter links the "coming of our Lord Jesus Christ in power" with his witness of the Majestic Glory displayed in the transfiguration. If, as is thought, Peter stands behind Mark's gospel and if Peter is the author of this epistle, this provides pretty strong evidence that Mark intends for his readers to link the statements made by Christ with the event that follows.

Comment: Thanks for bringing in 1 Peter to this discussion.  I had never noticed the connection before!

Comment: Bringing in the verse from 2 Peter nailed everything. Thanks indeed for clearing my doubts.

Answer (score 6):

Jesus was talking here about revealing His full glory. He revealed it to Peter, James and John.
The sabbath, the Old Testament feasts, the sabbath year, the jubilee year were all a foretaste pointing to Jesus as the return to the reality of Eden in New Jerusalem. So the fact that both Matthew and Mark tell us that Jesus transfigured in front of those three has a deep theological meaning.

Matthew 16-17:

*27 For the Son of man shall come in the glory of his Father with his angels; and then he shall reward every man according to his works.
28 Verily I say unto you, There be some standing here, which shall not taste of death, till they see the Son of man coming in his kingdom.
1 And after six days Jesus taketh Peter, James, and John his brother, and bringeth them up into an high mountain apart,
2 And was transfigured before them: and his face did shine as the sun, and his raiment was white as the light.
3 And, behold, there appeared unto them Moses and Elias talking with him.
4 Then answered Peter, and said unto Jesus, Lord, it is good for us to be here: if thou wilt, let us make here three tabernacles; one for thee, and one for Moses, and one for Elias.
5 While he yet spake, behold, a bright cloud overshadowed them: and behold a voice out of the cloud, which said, This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased; hear ye him.*

Mark 9:

*1 And he said unto them, Verily I say unto you, That there be some of them that stand here, which shall not taste of death, till they have seen the kingdom of God come with power.
2 And after six days Jesus taketh with him Peter, and James, and John, and leadeth them up into an high mountain apart by themselves: and he was transfigured before them.
3 And his raiment became shining, exceeding white as snow; so as no fuller on earth can white them.
4 And there appeared unto them Elias with Moses: and they were talking with Jesus.*

Comment: Are you saying Mark 9:2 was "the Kingdom of God come with power"?

Comment: Yes. Jesus, the Son of man appeared to the three as the Ancient of days (Daniel 7), the one whom Moses and Elijah saw at Sinai.

Comment: So Jesus = the Kingdom of God?

Answer (score 4):

The most authoritative Church commentators in antiquity understood Jesus here to be referring to the Transfiguration (Matthew 17:1-8; Mark 9:2-8; Luke 9:28-36).  It is no coincidence that the Transfiguration is the very next event the Synoptics recount after Jesus says *There may be some standing here ...* (Matthew 16:28; Mark 9:1; Luke 9:2) - with Matthew and Mark recalling that it occurred 6 days later, and Luke recalling that it occurred *about eight days* later.

John Chrysostom (c 349-407), commenting on Matthew's version, comments:

> Inasmuch as He had discoursed much of dangers and death, and of His own passion, and of the slaughter of the disciples, and had laid on them those severe injunctions ... He willing to assure their very sight, and to show what kind of glory that is wherewith He is to come, so far as it was possible for them to learn it; even in their present life He shows and reveals this; that they should not grieve any more ...
>
> Having discoursed of hell, and of the kingdom (for as well by saying, *He that findeth his life shall lose it, and whosoever will lose it for my sake, shall find it*<sup>1</sup> as by saying, *He shall reward every man according to his works*<sup>2</sup>, He had manifested both of these): having, I say, spoken of both, the kingdom indeed He shows in the vision, but hell not yet.<sup>3</sup>

Cyril of Alexandria (378-444) writes on Luke's version:

> He says, *I say unto you, there are some of those standing here, who shall not taste of death until they have seen the kingdom of God.* Does He mean that the measure of their lives will be so greatly prolonged as even to reach to that time when He will descend from heaven at the. consummation of the world, to bestow upon the saints the kingdom prepared for them? Even this was possible for Him: for He is omnipotent: and there is nothing impossible or difficult to His all-powerful will. But by the kingdom of God He means the sight of the glory in which He will appear at His manifestation to the inhabitants of earth: for He will come in the glory of God the Father, and not in low estate like unto us. How therefore did He make those who had received the promise spectators of a thing so wonderful? He goes up into the mountain taking with Him three chosen disciples: and is transformed to so surpassing and godlike a brightness, that His garments even glittered with rays of fire, and seemed to flash like lightning. And besides, Moses and Elijah stood at Jesus' side, and spake with one another of His departure.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>Matthew 16:25</sup>
<sup>2.</sup> <sup>*Ibid.* v.27</sup>
<sup>3.</sup> <sup>[*Homily LVI on Matthew*](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf110.iii.LIV.html) (tr. from Greek)</sup>
<sup>4.</sup> <sup>[[*Sermon LI on Luke*](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/cyril_on_luke_05_sermons_47_56.htm#SERMON%20LI) (tr. from Syriac)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In the context, Yahuwshuwa (Jesus) is speaking of the time when he shall come in glory and judge every man according to his works. In Matthew 16:24 it says he spoke these words to his disciples,  but if we cross reference it to mark 9:1 and 8:34 we see that he spoke these words to his disciples and the multitude of people with them.

So he said "*some of you shall not taste death* ",  only a remnant of the first generation of Israel would be saved therefore he said "*some*". They would not taste death.  Here are some verses to explain what he meant by that:

> john 11:26 "whosoever liveth and believeth in me shall **never die**"

and

> John 8:51 " if a man keep my saying,  **he shall never see death"**.
>
> Hebrews 2:9 (kjv) "But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than
> the angels for the suffering of death, crowned with glory and honour;
> that he by the grace of God should **taste death** for every man"

So out of the multitude of people that Yahuwshuwa spoke to, only a remnant received everlasting life and therefore never taste death.  Because Yahuwshuwa would taste death for those believers upon the cross . And yes they will "see" the kingdom coming in glory at the ressurection of the dead.

Answer (score 1):

@ ארקדיוס has answered well that in Matthew 16:27-17:5 as well as Mark 9:1-4  the Lord is not speaking about everyone, but explicitly says that "there are *some* among you", and in the immediate sequel it is said that He takes three of His disciples - Peter, James and John to show them His trasfiguration, His divine glory on mt. Tabor. And exactly this is to see and perceive the Kingdom of Heaven, to be in touch with divine Glory, His Grace, His uncreated Activities/Operations and get divinized and transfigured through Them.

This was felt by Peter who wanted to remain eternally on the mt. Tabor, smacking the taste of Eternal Kingdom already being on earth, before his, John's and James' death, as the Lord promised few days before.

Yet, in Mark 14 He rather speaks about His eschatological Second Coming when not *some*, but *all* humans without exception will see Him, both those who will be alive at this time and also the dead, whom He will resurrect; and either this resurrection will allow them to see Him coming in His divine glory also with the physical eyes of their newly resurrected bodies, or already then, when their undying personalities are featuring as yet disembodied souls, they will perceive His Second Coming in glory at the end of the times, even shortly before resurrection that will follow this non-physical-eye vision; or both together, with a short hiatus of time: first they will perceive the glory of His Second Coming only in a disembodied state and then also in the embodied state, with also physical eyes, after the resurrection of their bodies, that is to say the reunion with their resurrected bodies of the living disembodied souls/personalities.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

This is about being able to understand the knowledge of the mysteries of the kingdom.  The power of death and life is in the tongue …and they that love it shall eat the fruit of it.  When one hears the His knowledge (as He opens up the Scriptures to our understanding), we are to take heed on how we hear.

The only way to enter in to understanding His knowledge is to become humble (humble as a child as far behaving in evil opposition to what one hears) as the disciples did humble themselves upon the mountain .

They “fell on their face and were sore afraid”….they did fear God and keep His commandments and humbled themselves as they heard His voice instructing them to hear His Son.

> Matthew 17:5-7 KJV (5)  *While he yet spake, behold, a bright cloud
>   overshadowed them: and behold a voice out of the cloud, which said,
>   This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased; hear ye him. (6) 
>   **And when the disciples heard it, they fell on their face, and were
>   sore afraid**.*

Only then can one “stand” before the Son.

> (7)  ***And Jesus came and touched them, and said, Arise, and be not
>   afraid.***

John did fall at His feet as "dead"...that is, he humbled himself and was able to then "stand" before the Son.

> Revelation 1:17-18 KJV (17)  ***And when I saw him, I fell at his feet as
>   dead. And he laid his right hand upon me, saying unto me, Fear not***; I
>   am the first and the last: (18)  I am he that liveth, and was dead;
>   and, behold, I am alive for evermore, Amen; and have the keys of hell
>   and of death.

We also are to hear as He comes to open up the Scriptures (Moses and Elijah….the Law and the Prophets) to our hearing ears.

Whosoever shall not receive the kingdom of God as a little child (being humble) will in no wise enter in.  They cannot understand His words then.

> Luke 18:15-17 KJV (15)  *And they brought unto him also infants, that
>   he would touch them: but when his disciples saw it, they rebuked them.
>   (16)  But Jesus called them unto him, and said, Suffer little children
>   to come unto me, and forbid them not: for of such is the kingdom of
>   God. (17)  **Verily I say unto you, Whosoever shall not receive the
>   kingdom of God as a little child shall in no wise enter therein**.*

The power of death and life is in the tongue….and those who love it shall eat the fruit thereof…whether it be death or life.

When one uses their tongue for evil, they “taste” of death and will not be able to enter in.  His disciples did not “taste of death” and were able to understand.

> Proverbs 18:20-21 KJV (20)  ***A man's belly shall be satisfied with the
>   fruit of his mouth; and with the increase of his lips shall he be
>   filled. (21)  Death and life are in the power of the tongue: and they
>   that love it shall eat the fruit thereof***.

The Son comes in the kingdom to open up the Scriptures to our hearing ears.  His sayings are the “angels”….or messengers…that we are not to be ashamed of.  We are not to be ashamed of His testimony as He opens up the Scriptures to our understanding.

> Luke 9:26-27 KJV (26)  ***For whosoever shall be ashamed of me and of my
>   words, of him shall the Son of man be ashamed, when he shall come in
>   his own glory, and in his Father's, and of the holy angels.***

The only way to “stand” before the Son of man is not to use the tongue for evil at what hears.

They will not “taste of death”….that is, use the tongue for evil speaking against what one hears…until they see (KNOW) the kingdom of God as they will be able to enter in to understand the knowledge of the mysteries of the kingdom.

> (27)  ***But I tell you of a truth, there be some standing here, which
>   shall not taste of death, till they see the kingdom of God.***

The Son of man shall come in the glory of His Father with His angels….His sayings…His interpretations of the Scriptures.

He shall then reward every man according to what man’s works towards the hearing of  His interpretations of the Scriptures….Moses and Elijah “talk” with Him. Those who will humble themselves will then be able to "stand" before Him to hear.

Some will do evil as they will resist what they hear and speak evil….taste of death.

Others will do good towards what they hear….tasting life...for death and life are in the power of the tongue and we are to choose wisely choosing life and not death.

> Matthew 16:27-28 KJV (27)  *F**or the Son of man shall come in the glory
>   of his Father with his angels; and then he shall reward every man
>   according to his works.** (28)  Verily I say unto you, There be some
>   standing here, which shall not taste of death, till they see the Son
>   of man coming in his kingdom.*

The disciples upon the holy mountain did humble themselves and did listen.  They did hear a voice from Heaven confirming that this is His Son speaking and were to hear Him.   They did glorify the Father and the Son.

> 2 Peter 1:16-21 KJV (16)  *For we have not followed cunningly devised
>   fables, when we made known unto you the power and coming of our Lord
>   Jesus Christ, but were eyewitnesses of his majesty. (17)  For he
>   received from God the Father honour and glory, when there came such a
>   voice to him from the excellent glory, **This is my beloved Son, in whom
>   I am well pleased.** (18)  And this voice which came from heaven we
>   heard, when we were with him in the holy mount.*

Today, we have a more sure word of prophecy.

Rather than hearing an audible voice coming from Heaven confirming that this is His Son, we have a more sure confirmation within us as the Light arises within our very own darkened/obscured hearts that this is His Son whom we are to hear as He opens up…interprets…. the Scriptures (Moses and Elijah) to our hearing ears.

> (19)  *We have also a more sure word of prophecy; w**hereunto ye do well
>   that ye take heed, as unto a light that shineth in a dark place, until
>   the day dawn, and the day star arise in your hearts:** (20)  Knowing
>   this first, **that no prophecy of the scripture is of any private
>   interpretation**. (21)  For the prophecy came not in old time by the
>   will of man: but holy men of God spake as they were moved by the Holy
>   Ghost.*

The Lord comes to interpret the Scriptures with His holy words…sayings…. “angels”.

Some will be caught unawares when a “stranger”...those brothers who are moved to speak as moved by the Holy Spirit... comes along to speak His words.   They will be found not remembering to let brotherly love continue and will go about “killing the messengers” of His words.  They will not humble themselves .  They  will not be hospitable. They are using their tongues to "taste of death".

> Luke 21:34-38 KJV (34)  ***And take heed to yourselves, lest at any time
>   your hearts be overcharged with surfeiting, and drunkenness, and cares
>   of this life, and so that day come upon you unawares***.

As a snare shall it come on all of those who “dwell on the face of the whole earth” ….that is, upon those who are dwelling on earthly wisdom…..envy, strife, contentions, wrath, etc.   These are people who will not be found “awake” to His righteousness and will be tempted to speak out in evil….not humbling themselves.

> (35)  **For as a snare shall it come on all them that dwell on the face
>   of the whole earth.**

To “watch” is to remember to always let brotherly love continue. They will humble themselves at the hearing of His voice as He interprets the Scriptures.   To “pray” is to let our words always be seasoned with grace. They will be able to “stand” before the Son of man.

> (36)  ***Watch ye therefore, and pray always, that ye may be accounted
>   worthy to escape all these things that shall come to pass, and to
>   stand before the Son of man.***

This is about His coming to teach us…to interpret the Scriptures.   The children of the Day will hear Him teaching while those of the “night” are forgetting to let brotherly love continue and will not be able to receive His teachings as they use their tongues for evil….the “tasting of death”.

> (37)  ***And in the day time he was teaching in the temple; and at night
>   he went out, and abode in the mount that is called the mount of
>   Olives.***

The Light dawns within our very own hearts….and the people came “early in the morning” to Him in the temple for the purpose of hearing Him.

> (38)  **And all the people came early in the morning to him in the
>   temple, for to hear him.**

To continue in “prayer” is to let our speech always be filled with grace and peace so that we may enter in through the door of utterance to know the mystery of Christ and be thankful for what we shall hear.

> Colossians 4:2-6 KJV (2)  ***Continue in prayer, and watch in the same
>   with thanksgiving;*** (3)  Withal praying also for us, that God would
>   **open unto us a door of utterance, to speak the mystery of Christ,** for
>   which I am also in bonds: (4)  That I may make it manifest, as I ought
>   to speak.

Let brotherly love continue and entertain “strangers”….walking in wisdom to those who are without…so that we may enter in to understand the mysteries of the kingdom.   to "pray always" is to let our speech be always be with grace and seasoned with salt...with peace...towards all people.

> (5)  *Walk in wisdom toward them that are without, redeeming the time.
>   (6)  **Let your speech be alway with grace, seasoned with salt,** that ye
>   may know how ye ought to answer every man.*

To “taste of death” is to be found speaking out in evil towards those “strangers”

Answer (score 0):

These verses are clear evidence that Jesus believed the "Kingdom" would break in within the generation of people then living.  Matthew 24:34: "... this generation will not pass away till all these things take place" has a similar meaning.

Many later NT writings point the same direction.  Paul wrote that "time has grown very short" (1 Cor 7:29), the author of 1 Peter wrote "the end of all things is at hand", author of 1 John wrote "we know that it is the last hour" (1 John 2:18), Revelation talks about "what must soon take place" at the beginning, and "the time is near" at the end.

In short, Jesus and his followers mistakenly proclaimed an imminent end-times.

"In the decades after Jesus' death, then, the Christians had to revise their first expectation again and again. This makes it very probable that the expectation originated with Jesus. We make sense of these pieces of evidence if we think that Jesus himself told his followers that the Son of Man would come while they still lived. The fact that this expectation was difficult for Christians in the first century helps prove that Jesus held it himself." (E.P. Sanders, *The Historical Figure of Jesus*)

Some claim that the so-called "Transfiguration" was meant by Matt 16:28.  But does something that supposedly happened a mere six days later fit with "some standing here will not taste death"?  That verse implies a more future time: some people standing there would die, but some would not. It fits perfectly with "this generation will not pass away", meaning some of "this generation" will still be alive.

The clincher is the immediate preceding context in Matt 16:27: the Son of Man coming in glory with his angels, judging every man.  Clearly a reference to the imminent Kingdom coming.

Answer (score 0):

A movement began after the Babylonian conquest of Jerusalem in 586 BCE that developed into what was called apocalypticism. The basis for the belief was that, with the fall of Jeruselem and the destruction of the 1st temple, clearly forces of evil were in control of the world. The belief was that God would at some point correct this and good would rule and the righteous would be rewarded. God would do this by delivering a Messiah who would be a powerful man from the lineage of David. He would be a) a king, a military leader b) a prophet c) some cosmic figure (Son of Man?) who would lead Israel against the evil forces and win.

By the time of Jesus this had morphed into the understanding that this world would end and a new world, the Kingdom of God, would be in it's place. This is not heaven as we understand it. There would be a bodily resurrection of all who had lived and they would be judged as to their righteousness and those who were righteous would live on in the Kingdom of God where all things were as they should be.

**Thy kingdom come**
Thy will be done
**on Earth** as it is in heaven

Jesus is saying that the time is imminent. Mark 9:1 "some standing here will not taste death before the Kingdom of God has come with power". That is, within a generation, before some of you die, the Kingdom of God will come to power.

By the time Luke was written, it was clear that this wasn't happening so the verse was changed and the "come to power" was removed.

Also, the references to all 3 synoptic gospels is problematic. These are individual books that reflect the philosophy (theology and christology) of the writer. What Luke calls the Kingdom of God may not be what Mark or Matthew believes. You can't conflate the three.

Answer (score 0):

It’s ***possible*** that Jesus was referring to the coming **eschatological death** at the end of this Age.

Let’s put the text before us:

> “For **the Son of Man** is going to come in the glory of His Father with
> His angels, and will then repay every man according to his deeds.
> “Truly I say to you, there are some of those who are standing here who
> will not **taste death** until they see the Son of Man **coming in His
> kingdom**.”” ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭16:27-28‬

These verses have been confusing for many, in fact, there are quite a few alternative interpretations for this “tasting of death” that Jesus mentions.

Some interpret it as the transfiguration, others interpret it as the Resurrection of Christ, etc.

The view I believe Jesus is referring to is a figure of speech to refer to the **Second Death**.  The Second Death (the Lake of Fire) is **not** mentioned in any of the 4 gospels.  Yet in the 4 Gospels, Jesus had used figurative language multiples times.

The term “**Second Death**” is only found in the Book of Revelation: (Rev 2:11, 20:6, 20:14, 21:8).

Jesus spoke figuratively in the following examples:

> “These things I have spoken to you in **figurative language**; but the
> time is coming when I will no longer speak to you in figurative
> language, but I will tell you  plainly about the Father. John 16:25

See also: **John 10:6**(diff translations say: parable, illustration, figure of speech)
**John 10:9** (“I am the Door”)

So back to **Matthew 16:28**, it’s possible that Jesus was speaking of tasting the second death & not the first death.

Another Scriptural example to contend for this view:

> “This He said, and after that He *said to them, “**Our friend Lazarus
> has fallen asleep**; but I go, so that I may awaken him out of sleep.”
> The disciples then said to Him, “Lord, if he has fallen asleep, he
> will recover.” **Now Jesus had spoken of his death, but they thought
> that He was speaking of literal sleep**. So Jesus then said to them
> **plainly**, “**Lazarus is dead**,” ‭‭John‬ ‭11:11-14‬

Also comparing Christ’s second coming with **Matthew 16:28** is Matthew 13:

> “Then He left the crowds and went into the house. And His disciples
> came to Him and said, “Explain to us the parable of the tares of the
> field.” And He said, “The one who sows the good seed is the Son of
> Man, and the field is the world; and as for the good seed, these are
> the sons of the kingdom; and the tares are the sons of the evil one;
>
> and the enemy who sowed them is the devil, and the harvest is the end
> of the age; and the reapers are angels. So **just as the tares are
> gathered up and burned with fire**, so shall it be at the end of the
> age.
>
> ***The Son of Man will send forth His angels, and they will gather out of His kingdom all stumbling blocks, and those who commit lawlessness,
> and will throw them into the furnace of fire; in that place there will
> be weeping and gnashing of teeth***. Then the righteous will shine
> forth as the sun in the kingdom of their Father. He who has ears, let
> him hear.” ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭13:36-43‬

**CONCLUSION**

Those who are “thrown into a furnace of fire” will ultimately taste of the second death soon after: (**Revelation 20:11-15**)

Answer (score -2):

it could mean that for some the real death will come with the coming of God's Kingdom.

if those who actualy heard this verse are actually still alive today,... the verse says: "you will taste death, when the Kingdom comes".

the verse does not actualy imply that some will live as long as the kingdom doesnt come, but that they will 'taste death' only when it comes.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to visit the [tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site. Due to the [nature](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-before-they-post-bad-answers/803#803) of this site, 
references may be [required](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/735/what-kind-of-site-do-we-ultimately-want-to-have/777#777) in order to support your conclusions.

Answer (score -3):

The original of this passage is in Mark's Gospel, simply because it is the strong consensus of New Testament scholars that *Mark* was written first and was [the main source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcan_priority) used by the authors of the other two synoptic gospels. Thus, the most reliable way to establish the original meaning of this passage seems to be to look in *Mark*. The term 'kingdom of God' can tend to hide meaning and, in *[Mark as Story](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Mark_as_Story.html?id=H1oqpGN5WeMC)*, Rhoads, Dewey and Michie suggest a better translation to be 'rule of God', the Greek being capable of either meaning but 'rule of God', although less regal, a more straightforward reading in the English language.

In Mark 9:1, Jesus is prophesying his second coming, a prophecy he repeats in more dramatic detail in chapter 13. Mark has the ability to create relationships between events by the use of several rhetorical literary devices, including intercalations (literary sandwiches), chiastic structures, parallel structures and proximity. In this case, the prophecy in Mark 9:1 is linked, as pair X, in a [proposed parallel structure](https://www.academia.edu/12106716/A_Proposed_Framework_Structure_of_Mark_s_Gospel) of *Mark*, a literary relationship that demonstrates authorial intent. Mark 9:1 also follows seamlessly after a prophecy of the crucifixion in verse 8:31, with just a short intervening passage that hints of Peter's feelings of shame after the three denials.

> Mark 8:31: And he began to teach them, that the Son of man must suffer many things, and be rejected of the elders, and of the chief priests, and scribes, and be killed, and after three days rise again.
>
> Mark 9:1 (KJV): And he said unto them, Verily I say unto you, That **there be some of them that stand here, which shall not taste of death, till they have seen the kingdom of God come with power**.

[Mark chapter 13](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Mark-Chapter-13/) opens with a graphic description of the events of the First Roman-Jewish War and the civil war that erupted within Jerusalem even as it was being besieged. Then they are told that Jesus will come with great power and glory before his present generation had passed:

> Mark 13:26-30 And then shall they see the Son of man coming in the clouds with great power and glory. And then shall he send his angels, and shall gather together his elect from the four winds, from the uttermost part of the earth to the uttermost part of heaven. Now learn a parable of the fig tree; When her branch is yet tender, and putteth forth leaves, ye know that summer is near: So ye in like manner, when ye shall see these things come to pass, know that it is nigh, even at the doors. Verily I say unto you, that **this generation shall not pass**, till all these things be done.

Jesus did not literally prophesy his return on clouds within the lifetimes of some to whom he spoke, because had he done so, he would have been wrong. But the author of *Mark* had seen the tumultuous events of 70 CE and believed they were a portent of the second coming. This is what was meant by "will not taste death until they see the kingdom of God."

By the time the Gospels of Matthew and Luke were written, it was becoming clear that Jesus' generation had passed away without having seen Jesus return to establish the kingdom of God, so in copying Mark chapter 13, they emphasised that no one knew when Jesus would return, but they did copy the less obvious prophecy in Mark 9:1.