# Meaning of Matthew 16:28

Tags: greek, matthew, jesus

None the disciples who heard Jesus speak the words of Mat 16:28 is alive today. So what did Jesus really mean? What is it that some of them would see in their lifetime?

Matthew 16:28 “Truly I tell you, some who are standing here will not taste death before they see the Son of Man coming in his kingdom.”

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) This is a great question! However, it's already been asked here before. The good news is that you don't have to wait for answers! You can [head over to the existing question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/111/) and read them now :)