# What Was Jesus Saying? Who was He referring to in this verse?

Tags: matthew, death

Matthew 16:28 “Assuredly, I say to you, there are some standing here who shall not taste death till they see the Son of Man coming in His kingdom.”

Comment: John Chrysostom's interpretation is [here](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf110.iii.LIV.html); Cyril of Alexandria's [here](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/cyril_on_luke_05_sermons_47_56.htm#SERMON+LI).  Both date from the 4th century, but neither are cited in any of the other answers.  You will notice that the Transfiguration appears very shortly after Jesus says this (Matthew 17:1ff, Mark 9:2ff, Luke 9:28ff).

Comment: @NigelJ - in fairness, Origen seems not to have interpreted the passage in terms of the Transfiguration and I ran across an Orthodox commentary by an extremely conservativebishop that doesn't bring up the Transfiguration in his commentaries (he almost always summarizes patristic views).  Ellicott doesn't like the explanation and dismisses it.  But seems to be almost the consensus view during the first millennium.

Comment: @user33515 I think the close juxtaposition of the transfiguration to the saying of Jesus leaves no doubt and that interpretation fully satisfies me, myself.

Comment: @NigelJ - I opted to post a [new answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/31592/18696) to the other question.  As far as letting duplicates stand, there seems to be a predilection against it.

Comment: @user33515 I know what I was thinking of now. 'If I will that he tarry till I come' could be interpreted to mean his 'coming' in vision in the Revelation. Bit of brainslip, there.

Comment: I believe that this passage refers to John. He saw the kingdom in vision whilst writing the Book of Revelation, and even tasted the scroll given to him by an angel during these visions...Rev 10:10 it was sweet to eat but turned sour in his stomach. Then Rev 21:22 "And I saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband."